# Is there a way to set a unique ID to a place holder in powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, python, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using python-pptx to fill in placeholder text in the script, the powerpoint file itself is kinda like the template for position objects, since those will be done by none programmers.

Anyway, I found there is a thing called tags for text placeholders inside the data, is there a way to set it inside of powerpoint? I've looked through slide master and just can't find it, any other way of independently putting some kind of identifier on a placeholder would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Every shape, slide and presentation has a .Tags collection
You add tags via the .Tags.Add method: .Tags.Add "TagName", "TagValue"
You retrieve tag values similarly:  .Tags("TagName")

You can add tags to shapes and placeholders on master slides and layouts but when you create a new slide based on a layout, the placeholders are copied from the layout to the new slide and don't inherit the tags from the layout. Shapes that aren't placeholder on layouts don't even exist on slides based on the layout; they're only on the layout.

Likewise, the .Name property of placeholders in layouts/masters isn't retained in slides based on the layouts.

Rather than working with the masters/layouts and placeholders on them, start with a pre-formatted slide that meets your requirements and merge your data into it. Or if you need multiple slides, make duplicates of the original slide and merge data into each slide as needed. Tags added to the original slide will be retained in copies of the slide.